# Select number from text

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, wordpress, text

I have a body element with class attribute that changes depending on current page and I need to extract the ID number of current category ("term-21") and save it into variable using JS or jQuery.

How can I do it?

HTML:

```
<body class="archive tax-product_cat term-name term-21"></body>
```

JS variable should be like:

```
var catNumber = "21";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i got you coreclty you can do this:

```js
const cat = (document.body.className.match(/term-(\d+)/) || [,0])[1]

console.log(cat)
```

```html
<body class="archive tax-product_cat term-name term-21"> </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var cname=document.body.className.split("-");
var catNumber = cname[cname.length-1];
```

Comment: This won't work if `term-21` is not last class, better way would be to use `classList` and than finding class using `backwards for loop` and index of